# SCSS (SASS) Efficiency Assistance

Tags: html, css, scripting, sass

I was just wondering if anyone knew anyway i could make the below code anymore efficient or dynamic, I have already achieved the desired result i would just like to know if it can be made to work better.

[The Script](http://www.innercitywinemakers.com.au/arbitrary/script.scss)

Any answer would be greatly appreciated,
Cheers,
Jackson Redmond

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to have a look [compass](http://compass-style.org/). It provides a lot of useful mixins (e.g. [box-shadow](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_shadow/) or [border-radius](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/border_radius/)) for Scss or Sass. They are working on an animation module, so have a look at [this commit](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/commit/9b924243ff7fb543ea8fdce572cf3fc94ef147ba) to see how they are implementing this.